# Multiple content in a single view - Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Is that possible, in Drupal 7 or 8, to use multiple content type in a single view, ordered by a taxonomy that those are shearing.

For now, i get to have one content type, ordered by his attached taxonomy, but i can't figure out how to add an other content type witch is using the same taxonomy.

The difference between the two content type is that the first one have two more field. The second one will have later an other field.

Is that possible and how to do that?

Thank's !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible and if your question is full detailed very easy:
Just open in "Filter Criteria" filter called "Content: Type" and in opened window choose "Is one of" at the right part and your content type(s) at the left part

[image: Screen for you]